# How to cast const unsigned int array into int array

Tags: arrays, casting, integer, constants, unsigned-integer

I'd like to cast a `const unsigned int*` array into an `int*` array.
`static_cast` and `const_cast`, however, fail.

```cpp
const unsigned int* getArray()
{
  static unsigned int a[3];
  a[0] = 0;
  a[1] = 1;
  a[2] = 2;
  return a;
}
int main()
{
  const unsigned int * a = getArray();
  const_cast<int*>(a); // fail
  static_cast<int*>(a); // fail
}
```

Comment: Is that your real code?  `getArray` doesn't even have a `return` statement.  Besides that, returning the address of a local variable (like it seems you intend to do) is bad news.

Comment: @CarlNorum `getArray()` is just to replace a call to a larger library over which I have no control. -- I agree that passing around raw pointers isn't nice.

Comment: Passing pointers around is fine.  Returning pointers to local variables isn't.  Why not just declare `a` with `static`?  Then it will be correct and won't confuse future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `const_cast` can't change the type, just the `const`ness.
2. `static_cast` can't take away the `const`, nor can it change between those pointer types.

What it looks like you want is:

```
int *b = reinterpret_cast<int *>(const_cast<unsigned int *>(a));
```

You can also just use a C-style cast in this case:

```
int *b = (int *)a;
```

Comment: So concatenating the two might work? This `unsigned int * b = const_cast<unsigned int*>(a);` at least casts away the `const` while this `int * c = static_cast<int*>(b);` still fails. I'll adapt the question.

Comment: No, you also can't change the pointer types with `static_cast`.  Editing.